# Make columns unsortable in dataTables jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables

I am using DataTables jQuery plugin for table representation.

The first column of my table is a row counter and I don't want to sort counter numbers in it. How can I make these column unsortable?

[image]

```
$('#usersTable').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'span6'<'#jTableHeader'l>><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'<'#jTableFooter'>><'span6'p>>",

        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10,25,50,-1],[10,25,50,"All"]],

        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "aaSorting": [[2, "asc"]],
        "aoColumns": [
            {"bSortable": false},
            {"bSortable": false},
            {"sType": "string"},
            {"sType": "string"},
            {"sType": "string"},
            {"sType": "date"},
            {"bSortable": false}
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant. The column would be sorted anyway, if you sort one of the other columns.

However, if you just want to maintain the `#`-order, regardless of the content / sorting of the other columns you could easily mimick the desired behaviour. Eg, I think what you *really* wants is always to have `#1`, `#2`, `#3` in the first column, no matter what - right?

Consider this code, using `fnDrawCallback` to ensure the first column always contain ascending numbers `1..n`, a row counter :

```js
var dataTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    aoColumns: [ 
       { "bSortable": false },
       null,
       null,
       null,
       null
    ],
    fnDrawCallback : function( oSettings ) {
       $(this).find('tbody tr').each(function(index) {
         $(this).find('td').first(0).text(index+1);
       });
     }
});
```

see working fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2bye2/**

Comment: Thanks, but in my case right solution is `$(this).find('td').eq(1).text(index + 1);`